# Defining a good structure of a user activity logger

Tags: php, logging, silex, php-7

Im developing this web application using the Silex framework and I would like to store different user activities/events in my database(mysql) e.g. when the user login, logout, create content, update content etc.
The purpose of this log is to go back in time at a certain date and see e.g. user with ID 2 logged in 2 times, he created 2 new xx and updated 3 xx.

For each event I want to store in the database I want to save the userId of the user that is logged in, the event(a string e.g. login) and the url of the event e.g. https://mydomain.dev/login. But how can you go back then? Yes I also have a field on my table named created that is default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Im stuck at which direction I should create this Logger class.
At this moment, I have a LoggerInterface and in this I have defined a static log function.

```
interface LoggerInterface
{
    public static function log(LogEvent $logEvent);
}
```

Now my question is, what would be the most optimal way to create different activities.

Create a abstract LogEvent class that holds the properties of a log event like

```
abstract class LogEvent {
    protected $type;
    protected $url;
}
```

This way I can a class for each event and define my type in my e.g. LoginLogEvent class:

```
class LoginLogEvent extends LogEvent
{
    protected $type = 'login';
}
```

The way I define the type like this is that a good approach or should I create a constants file where I define all my activities that I want to track e.g.

```
class LogEvents
{
    const LOGIN = "login";
}
```

then in my LoginLogEvent class:

```
class LoginLogEvent extends LogEvent
{
    protected $type = LogEvents::LOGIN;
}
```

I could also create a constructor along these lines:

```
class LoginLogEvent extends LogEvent
{
    protected $type;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct($type, $url){
        $this->type= $type;
        $this->url= $url;
    }
}
```

Good stuff but what about when I want to log something.. I would probably create a LogHandler class something like this:

```
class LogHandler implements LoggerInterface
{
    public static function log(LogEvent $logEvent)
    {
        // TODO: Implement log() method.
    }
}
```

Then I would make a switch case on the $logEvent->type and basically write the event's type, url to the database.

Thank you and have a good weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

Silex already has support for [Monolog](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/monolog.html) to provide all the functionality you need. You can also add the `WebProcessor` to add URLs, IPs and more to the logged data, with a range of levels from debugging to critical & emergency statuses.